# Trust between EJBs

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x, jaas

I have a bunch of EJBs using declarative security and I need to make an EJB to trust on another one.

For example

```
class ServiceOne {

    @EJB
    private ServiceTwo service;

    @RolesAllowed("role1")
    public void doSomething() {
        // do several things here...
        service.giveMeInfo();
    }
}


class ServiceTwo {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext ejbCtx;

    @RolesAllowed("role2")
    public String giveMeInfo() {
        System.out.println("OK user " + ctx.getCallerPrincipal());
        return str;
    }
}
```

The user calling serviceOne.doSomething() has only "role1", he doesn't have "role2", that is needed to call giveMeInfo(), but I want to allow him call this method anyway, because it is from ServiceOne (which is allowed).

If I use a @RunAs based strategy, I loss information about the real user, since getCallerPrincipal() would give me only the role specified with anonymous principal, but I need to keep original caller information.

(ps: I'm using JBOSS eap 6.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare more than one role in @RolesAllowed:

```
class ServiceTwo {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext ejbCtx;

    @RolesAllowed({"role1", "role2"})
    public String giveMeInfo() {
        System.out.println("OK user " + ctx.getCallerPrincipal());
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the method giveMeInfo is not allowed for role1.
It should be allowed only when other the call is comming from other EJB.

Comment: There is no other way to do this if you want to preserve the authenticated identity

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answer.